# Expressing as a continued fraction

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

How can I express this as a continued fraction?

$\left(\frac{2207 + 987\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/8}$

Comment: You've asked sixteen questions and haven't accepted a single one. Continuing that will make some very clever people reluctant to provide an answer. It's polite to accept an answer that you think is good: it gives both you and the respondent a boost in reputation, which some people find important. To accept an answer, click on the check mark to the left of your question. Please do so.

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry. I didn't know that. Okay I will do that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = 2 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/\ldots))$$

Comment: Wow. I just had to evaluate the 8th root. Thanks!